# How to identify the same mouse when connected with USB receiver and USB cable in RawInput?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, raw-input

I am writing a WPF app in which I use RawInput.Sharp to invoke the RawInput API and I'm able to obtain the mouse list and listen to the mouse event I'm interested in. No problem for that part.

However, when I want to record the events from my mouse, I notice that it has different information when connected using the USB receiver and plugged with the USB cable.

Taking my mouse, which is a Logitech G Pro Wireless, as an example:

- When connected with the USB wireless receiver, I see "USB Receiver" in the "Settings/Devices" in Windows 10;
- When plugged with the USB Cable, I see "G Pro Wireless Gaming Mouse" in the same place.

What I get from RawInput API is similar. Product name, produce ID, device path, device handle, etc. are all different...

Is it possible to know that these two devices from the device list are of the same mouse?

**UPDATE 1: clarification of the question**

I want to use this app to count how many times the left button of my mouse is clicked. I'm now able to listen to the click event and record it.

However, when I want to go one step further to make the app only listen to one of my mice (e.g. the GPW), I got 2 problems:

1. GPW itself becomes 2 different devices when used wirelessly and plugged with USB cable. There seems no way to automatically identify and merge these devices.
2. My keyboard's USB receiver also appears in the device list, with the same name of my mouse's USB receiver, when I grab only "mouse" type of devices.

Here's what I see from Settings/Devices in Windows 10 when both of my mouse's and keyboard's USB receiver are plugged, and my mouse is plugged with USB cable:

[image: What I see from Settings/Devices in Windows 10]

The devices obtained using the following code which calls RawInput.Sharp:

[image: The devices obtained using RawInput.Sharp code]

```
    var devices = RawInputDevice.GetDevices();

    foreach (var mouse in devices.OfType<RawInputMouse>())
    {
        Text += "\n" + mouse.ManufacturerName + " " + mouse.ProductName + " " + mouse.Handle + "\n\t" +
                mouse.DevicePath + " " + mouse.VendorId + " " + mouse.ProductId + " " + mouse.UsageAndPage;
    }
```

Definition of `RawInputDevice.GetDevices()`:
https://github.com/mfakane/rawinput-sharp/blob/master/RawInput.Sharp/RawInputDevice.cs#L109

By the way, both USB receivers also show up if I change `devices.OfType<RawInputMouse>()` to `devices.OfType<RawInputKeyboard>()`.

Comment: No matter how hard you believe that those devices are the same, they aren't. One is a mouse, connected to a USB port, the other is a wireless mouse receiver. With the obvious out of the way, what *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Record how many times the left (or right) button are clicked for exactly the mouse (I may connect 2 different mice to the same computer) that I'm interested in.

Comment: @coolcfan so, what is the *problem* you are having, exactly? If you have 2 mice connected, they are separate devices, regardless of their types. Simply listen to the device you want. But since your chosen mouse identifies itself differently depending on whether is is wired or wireless, there is no way to know they are the same physical mouse.  So why not just present the user with a list of available mice and let them chose which mouse to listen to?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm also thinking about making it user dependent. But a problem would be... the user won't know which USB receiver is for the mouse. For example, my Logitech wireless keyboard's receiver also shows up, with the name "USB Receiver", in the mouse device list I get with raw input API......

Comment: @coolcfan are you stricting your device search to just mouse devices, or are you also including all USBs regardless of their type?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm stricting the device type to mouse. Is it possible for a device to be both "mouse" and "keyboard"? Both USB receivers for my mouse and keyboard have keyboard icons in the Win10 Settings/Devices page. I'll post code snippet and screenshots later to the post.

Comment: @coolcfan I meant **re**stricting, that was a typo. And no, I'm not aware of a device being both a keyboard and a mouse at the same time. It might help to see your actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated with the code, which is very simple. My listening code is actually working, I'm just confused by the results returned by "GetDevices"

Comment: USB devices can have multiple **interfaces** each communicating through **EndPoints**, which are communication pipes. In your case the device is a `USB Receiver` which have at least 2 interfaces: keyboard & mouse. When you connect directly the mouse you have a `G Pro Wireless Gaming Mouse` device with a single interface: a mouse. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match them with [HidD_GetSerialNumberString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getserialnumberstring) on a device interface handle. To obtain handle you need to call [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) on that `\\?\HID...` device interface file name. Also mouse devices are opened by system for read and write exclusively - so you need to provide `dwDesiredAccess` as **zero**, and `dwShareMode` as `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to open handle (which cannot be used to read HID data but can be used to read various HID attributes).

But not every HID device is providing serial number...